# Converting slice into array pointer

Tags: pointers, opengl, go, slice

I have this bit of code,

```
var buffers [2]uint32
gl.GenBuffers(2, /* What here! */)
```

*gl.GenBuffers()* asks for a int32 and a *uint32. In C, you'd pass an static array or a pointer to it and all would be good, but in Golang, a slice doesn't work...

Two ways I can think of are allocating a dynamic array, or converting the slice into a pointer array,

Bad thing is that I don't know how to do either...
I tried new, but it doesn't really work like malloc...
I'm stumped and any help would be greatly appeciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write:

```
var buffers [2]uint32
gl.GenBuffers(int32(len(buffers)), &buffers[0])
```

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var buffers [2]uint32
    fmt.Printf("%d %p\n", int32(len(buffers)), &buffers[0])
    fmt.Printf("%T %T\n", int32(len(buffers)), &buffers[0])
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/J-tKynWv5P1

Output:

```
2 0x10410020
int32 *uint32
```